# Runtime Stripping of Unused CSS

Tags: html, css, optimization, minify

I have an MVC site which renders a view to a string, then sends it as an email. I'd like to use Twitter's BootStrap to format this. I know I could just include the whole bootstrap.css in the head of the HTML email, but the vast majority are unused. Is there a way to minify/strip the unused styles at runtime and include them in the head?

Comment: Why do you want to include bootstrap? I doubt the HTML/CSS which is being used would be compatible with many email systems.

Comment: I think your best bet is setting up a Grunt task for removing all unused CSS. https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss